# Repeating no matter my input

Tags: java, infinite-loop, repeat

So the program that I am trying to write is something like this. The opponent picks a number at random where each number corresponding to a person. then the user does the same thing. then the out is to show what the user pick, what the opponent picked and who won that match. its similiar to rock, paper scissor but with some more stuff added to it. i also have to show the numbers of rounds played and how many times the user had won. But my problem is this. No matter what my input is, it keeps saying that i made an invalid choice and to pick it again. This is what I have.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int game=0;
    int won = 0; 
    int opponent;
    Random rand = new Random();
    System.out.println("Welcome to the game. Here are the rules:");        
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    rules();
    choices();
    int choice = selected(in);
    while (choice !=0) {
        rules();
        choices();
        choice = selected(in);
        opponent = opp();
        result(choice, opponent, in);
        game+=1;
    }
    System.out.println("You played " +game+" games.");
    System.out.println("Quitting");
}
public static void rules(){
    System.out.println("\nFlurg beats Stuga and Kvartal");
    System.out.println("Stuga beats Kvartal");
    System.out.println("Kvartal beats Lerberg");
    System.out.println("Lerberg beats Flurg and Stuga");
    System.out.println("The computer wins in the event of a tie.");
    System.out.println();
}
public static int opp(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    int opponent = rand.nextInt(4)+1;
    return opponent;
}

public static void choices(){
    System.out.println("Please select your choice:");
    System.out.println("'1' for Flurg ");
    System.out.println("'2' for Stuga ");
    System.out.println("'3' for Kvartal ");
    System.out.println("'4' for Lerberg ");
    System.out.println("'0' to Quit ");
    System.out.print("Selection: ");
}

public static int selected(Scanner in){
    int choice = in.nextInt();
    while (choice != 1 && choice != 2 &&
           choice != 3 && choice != 4 &&
           choice != 0) {
        System.out.println("Invalid choice");
    choices();
    choice = in.nextInt();
}
    return choice;
}

public static int result(int choice, int opponent, Scanner in) {
    int won=0;
    System.out.print("You picked:" +choice+". Opponent picked:" +opponent+".");
    if(choice == 1 && (opponent == 2) || (opponent == 3)){
        System.out.println("You won!");
        won+=1;
    }
    else if(choice == 2 && opponent == 3){
        System.out.println("You won!");
        won+=1;
    }
    else if(choice == 3 && opponent == 4){
        System.out.println("You won!");
        won=+1;
    }
    else if(choice == 4 && (opponent == 1 || opponent == 2)){
        System.out.println("You won!");
        won+=1;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("You lost!");
    }        
    return won;
}

}
```

***EDIT*** 
So I fixed exactly what i was told about the `!=1` part. but it is again looping. for some reason, it does not want to run `result()`

***EDIT#2***
Main also has been fixed with the similar problem.

***EDIT#3***
I have added more lines based on what I was told.

Comment: You're reading `choice` in as an int, not a char. `1 != '1'`, you need to remove the single quotes from your numbers in that while statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the found values to chars.

```
int choice = in.nextInt();
while (choice != '1' //...
```

However, this compares the entered numerical value to the ASCII-code of the character which is 49 for the character `'1'`. Therefore, your loop will continue until you enter one of the numbers 48 ('0') to 52 ('4').

You should compare to the numbers instead:

```
while (choice != 1 && choice != 2 && choice != 3 && choice != 4 && choice != 0) {
    System.out.println("Invalid choice");
}
```

The same goes for

```
while (choice !='0') {
    rules();
    choices();
    selected(in);   
    opp();
    result(choice, opponent, in);
}
```

in your `main` method -- change this to

```
while (choice != 0) { // change this to 0 instead of '0'
    rules();
    choices();
    choice = selected(in); // assign the value to choice
    opponent = opp(); // assign the value to opponent
    result(choice, opponent, in);
}
```

You also did not assign the return values of the methods to the local variables -- they are never going to change and the loop will never end like that!

Comment: So i fixed that part that you mention. However, i am having the loop again. the fix you mention fixed the invalid selection part.

Comment: @Jody see the update to my answer. @njzk2, thanks for pointing this out, I included that part explicitly. I didn't see that one because the OP's original question only mentioned the `"Invalid choice"` part.

Comment: i am starting to think my `while(choice !=0)` loop in main is wrong. reason is because it is that part that keeps repeating no matter what i do.

Comment: @Jody: I think you forgot to assign the return values of `opp();` and `selected(in);` to the corresponding variables -- see the latest edit of my answer for the required changes.

Comment: @pascalhein: so that was what I missed. I didn't realize that i had to do that part. I was going by an example that we went over in class. Now all that needs to get done is my input. for some reason, everything i put in makes the `selected(in);` take over and not keep my answer.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
choice != '1' && choice != '2' &&
choice != '3' && choice != '4' &&
choice != '0'
```

to this

```
choice != 1 && choice != 2 &&
choice != 3 && choice != 4 &&
choice != 0
```

What you were trying to do was int != char and the value for '1' in ASCII is 49 SO it was indeed not 1. You are reading int from the Scanner.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
int choice = in.nextInt();
while (choice != '1' && choice != '2' &&
       choice != '3' && choice != '4' &&
       choice != '0') {
    System.out.println("Invalid choice");
```

`nextInt()` will return the decimal value of an int type. (int)1 != (char)'1'. The easiest solution I can think of is

```
while (choice != 1 && choice != 2 &&
       choice != 3 && choice != 4 &&
       choice != 0) {
```